# LEFT JOIN с одинаковыми полями

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `description`:

```
id
title
text
text_ru
```

И таблица `description_title`:

```
id
text
text_ru
```

Нужно объединить данные этих таблиц по полю title -> id, сейчас написал такой запрос:

```
SELECT d.*, dt.* FROM description d LEFT JOIN description_title dt ON (d.title = dt.id) WHERE d.id = 1
```

Сейчас получается что поля с одинаковым названием в таблицах перебивают друг друга, можно ли их вернуть таким образом чтобы этого не происходило, например добавить какой-то префикс в результате к первой таблице и ко второй?

P.S. Вариант с перечислением полей каждой таблицы и заданием префиксов не подойдет, т.к. в эти таблицы будут добавляться новые поля, например `text_ua`, мультиязычность. Т.е. нужно вернуть все поля первой таблицы и все поля второй таблицы.

P.S.S. Сейчас результат такой: `id - title - text - text_ru - id - text - text_ru`. А нужно получить что-то наподобии такого: `table1_id - table1_title - table1_text - table1_text_ru - table2_id - table2_text - table2_text_ru`.

Comment: Почему, я пытаюсь написать универсальный запрос, результаты которого будут обрабатываться в php?

Comment: Чтобы при добавлении новых полей в таблицу, в сам sql запрос не нужно было бы вносить изменения.

Comment: _"Чтобы при добавлении новых полей в таблицу, в сам sql запрос не нужно было бы вносить изменения"_ не выйдет. А как вы в php будете отслеживать вновь появившиеся поля?

Comment: Одно из основных правил **никогда** не использовать `*` в SELECT запросе

Comment: Я понял, что вы имеете ввиду. Но боюсь mysql автоматически такого делать не умеет. Вам придется самим прописывать алиасы

Comment: Dmitry Kozlov, на сайте есть несколько языков, их ключевые слова `ua ru fr en`. Например в таблицу можно добавить поле text_fr и сразу получить его значение в php проверив по "text_" . "fr". Также кол-во языков со временем будет увеличиваться.

Comment: Anton Shchyrov, а что если нужно получить значение всех полей в таблице,  это только `*` и придется делать. Ну, можно еще перечислением всех полей, но здесь это не подходит.

Comment: @Shillkas, почему не подходит перечисление всех полей, я так и не понял?Если вы добавите новое поле в таблицу, вам потом в коде придется дописывать всё равно что-то. И подход с размножением полей вида `text_<lang>` плохой, лучше создать под это отдельную таблицу и соединяться с ней по нужному идентификатору языка.